# Turn off breakpoint in fiddler2

Tags: fiddler

Problem Description:
Unable to disable breakpoint in fiddler

Software:
I am using fiddler version: v4.6.20171.9220
browser: google chrome
OS windows 10

Scenario:
Created a BPU using QuickExec --> BPU superveda

this worked as expected but i am unable to turn off the breakpoint 
i am not using any filter 
i have tried clicking on go option, it clears the current breakpoint but when i refresh the webpage fiddler still  intercepts the URL

Assistance:
is there any other way to disable breakpoint

Comment: can u add a link from your fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

so just entering BPU in QuickExec resolves the issue